# int32 decoding with google protobuf between android and visual-c++

Tags: android, sockets, visual-c++, encoding, protocol-buffers

I'm having a problem communicating protobufs through tcp sockets where the client is working in Android emulator (running eclipse + ADP + SDK android-15) and the server in C++ (Visual Studio 2010), both on Windows 7. Protobuf version: 2.4.1

**.proto**

```
package pck;

option java_package = "my.messages.package";
option java_outer_classname = "ClassName"; 
option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME; 

message msg_name {
    optional int32 VARIABLE = 6;
    //moro...
    }
```

**client: android side**

```
msg_name outMsg = to_send.build();
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
outMsg.writeTo(output);
//now output.toString() is sent via tcp socket...
```

What I get, and the reason I'm asking here is: communication works, messages reach server endpoint, but values for the int32 variable are as following:

(values sent on android ->> values read on visual-c++ side)

- android: [0, 127]  ->> visual-c++: [0, 127] Works fine, ok.
- android: [128, 255] -->> visual-c++: 3104751
- android: [256, 383] -->> visual-c++: 5201903
- ...

So, is it a problem of encoding? Is my problem with protobufs on client-android side? (I must say it's my first day on android, opss!)